# Are negative values in css accepted?

Tags: css

Can negative values be used in CSS?

e.g:

```
margin:-11px 20px -18px 0px;
```

OR

is there a standard protocol that no negative values should be used?

Comment: yes but is not take to ie below 7

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the property. See individual property descriptions in CSS specifications. Regarding [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties), CSS 2.1 spec says: “Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits.”

Answer (score 1):

Yes, negative value in `margin` is **accepted** but in `padding` is not **accepted**.

As per [W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)